# Difference between generic declaration and providing class parameter

Tags: c#, generics

What differences are there between declaring:

```
GenericClass<T> genericInst = new GenericClass<T>();
```

and

```
GenericClass<baseClass> temp = new GenericClass<baseClass>();
```

Here the GenericClass is defined to be for `where T : baseClass`

GenericClass contains a generic list

```
private List<T> vals = new List<T>();
```

Comment: In what context are you using T above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, and please correct me if I'm wrong, that you are taking 'where T : baseClass' as if it were a default for type `T` to be a `baseClass`?

If so, this is not the case, the specialization `where T : baseClass` means that the type `T` must be `baseClass` or derived from `baseClass` (or implement if it were an interface instead of a class).

Thus, if you had:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : baseClass
{
}
```

Then you can say:

```
var x = new GenericClass<baseClass>();
```

Or

```
var y = new GenericClass<SomethignDerivedFromBaseClass>();
```

But you could not say:

```
var z = new GenericClass<int>();
```

Since `int` does not inherit from `baseClass`.

The only way to actually use `T` in the instantiation above is if you were actually calling that line of code from within the `GenericClass<T>`:

```
public GenericClass<T> where T : baseClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        GenericClass<T> genericInst = new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}
```

Or from another context where T is already known to be a sub-class of baseClass.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're wondering that if you had:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : baseClass
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Whether you could add things derived from baseClass into the list, and the answer is yes-ish.  The class `GenericClass<T>` could be declared for any `T` that inherits from baseClass.  But the `List<T>` would still be strongly typed to type `T`.

That is given these:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class SubClass : BaseClass { }
```

A `GenericClass<BaseClass>` could hold both `BaseClass` and `SubClass` in it's `List<T>` since `T` will be `BaseClass`.

But a `GenericClass<SubClass>` will have a `List<T>` where `T` will be `SubClass` and thus can only hold items of `SubClass` or inheriting from it.

Comment: Kind of.

My confusion lies in if i declare using the baseclass parameter, can't i just include my derived types in this generic collection by casting?

Comment: List<T> can hold items of types derived from T without casting, because  every T' is a T.  That is, a List<Shape> can hold Rectangles, Circles, and Squares.  That said, a List<Rectangle> cannot be cast to a List<Shape> directly or it would be problematic.

Comment: I think i misunderstand casting up the inheritance chain.

If the List<Shape> can hold Rectangles why do we need generics at all...

Comment: Because generics are type-safe.  If you have `List<Shape>` it prevents you from storing an `int` inside of it and getting a bad item back.  `List<Shape>` says you can store any shape it it, but nothing else.

Comment: OK...i can see how defining the generic class avoids having to define multiple classes for each type of collection.

And GenericClass<T> genericInst = new GenericClass<T>(); is only used in the class definition?

Comment: The `T` is typically only used in a generic definition, most of the rest of the time you'll be referring to it by its realized name (e.g. List<int>, List<string>, etc instead of List<T>)

Comment: Thanks, definitely clearer, though i'm still unsure as to when you'd use - GenericClass<T> genericInst = new GenericClass<T>();

Comment: Thanks...to avoid going into lengthy discussion i'll just think of the T in the defintion and not outside.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9058/discussion-between-gwizardry-and-james-michael-hare)